# Mockito Junit for returning List

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to write junit for this method returning country List

```
public List<String> getCountries(String countryCd) {

  String sql = "select COUNTRY_NAME from MY_COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY_CD = :countryCd ";
  List<String> countries;
  SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("countryCd", countryCd);
  countries = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql,parameters, (resultSet, rowNum) ->
            resultSet.getString("COUNTRY_NAME")));
  return countries
}
```

I tried something like this

```
Mockito.when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryJobs, parameters, String.class))
```

Comment: what is your question?
could you share how the class that owns getCountries() is built and which attributes it has?
what is the result of what you tried?

Comment: @germanio This List data is coming from backend and I am storing in response class as List<String> countries . I just want approach to create Junit for this use case. Hope this helps

Comment: It is unclear how you prepare queryJobs and parameters in your test

Answer (score 0):

MapSqlParameterSource inherits its equals method from Object.
This means that 2 parameter sources are equal only if they reference same instance.

You need to provide an argument matcher to compare this argument and not use equals method. The cleanest way to do it is via [Custom Argument Matcher](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers#custom-argument-matcher).

Alternatively, you relax the requirements for this argument and use `any(MapSqlParameterSource.class)` matcher.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Mockito.when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any(), any(), any())).thenRetrun(you v
```

Comment: Might you please give some explanation of how this works?  Code-only answers can sometimes be less helpful than code + explanation.  Also, your code `.thenRetrun(you v` seems to have been truncated.